# How to properly call C++ library function in Java Activity

Tags: c++, android-studio, opencv, cmake

I am using GitHub in-paint library https://github.com/cheind/inpaint in android studio
and trying to call jni fuction of inpainter in main activity but it is not resolving or getting recognized.
C++ is new to me so i am having issue.

in criminisi_inpainter.cpp file

there is this function

```
  void inpaintCriminisi(
    cv::InputArray image,
    cv::InputArray targetMask,
    cv::InputArray sourceMask,
    int patchSize)
{
    CriminisiInpainter ci;
    ci.setSourceImage(image.getMat());
    ci.setSourceMask(sourceMask.getMat());
    ci.setTargetMask(targetMask.getMat());
    ci.setPatchSize(patchSize);

    ci.initialize();

    while (ci.hasMoreSteps()) {
        ci.step();
    }

    ci.image().copyTo(image.getMat());
}
```

this native function i have to call in main activity

public native void inpaintCriminisi( ? , ? ,? , int z);

The issue is i do not understand what parameters would be provided here in main activity (JAVA)

In nativelib.cpp i am exporting jnicall function i give object parameters which is not exact parameters that should be defined.

```
  extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_raweeda_applicationc_MainActivity_inpaintCriminisi(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                                   jobject a, jobject b, jobject c,
                                                                    jint xl) {

    // TODO
    inpaintCriminisi(x,y,z,xl);

parameters are not object it just an example

}
```

this is the error i am recieving

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86 --target native-lib}
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/criminisi_inpainter.cpp.o
FAILED: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -ID:/opencv-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include --sysroot C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\native-lib.dir\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -c D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp
D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp:13:5: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]

    cv::InputArray ;

    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp:23:39: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

     inpaintCriminisi( cv::InputArray image,

                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^

D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp:24:28: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

            cv::InputArray targetMask,

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^

D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp:25:28: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

            cv::InputArray sourceMask,

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^

D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\native-lib.cpp:26:17: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

            int patchSize);

            ~~~ ^

1 warning and 4 errors generated.

FAILED: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android19 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -ID:/opencv-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include --sysroot C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/criminisi_inpainter.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\native-lib.dir\src\main\cpp\criminisi_inpainter.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/criminisi_inpainter.cpp.o -c D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\criminisi_inpainter.cpp
In file included from D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\criminisi_inpainter.cpp:7:

D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp/timer.h:83:1: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')

}

^

D:\2019_android\ApplicationC\app\src\main\cpp\criminisi_inpainter.cpp:10:10: fatal error: 'opencv' file not found

#include "opencv"

         ^~~~~~~~

2 errors generated.

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

because in nativelib.cpp
[image: error]

Comment: Hi Hasan, could you share your exception / error log?

Comment: i updated the question you can see error log.

Comment: This is a compilation error because inpaint library depends on opencv. You can get here the android version of opencv: https://opencv.org/platforms/android/

Try adding opencv as a dependency to your project and recompile your C++ code using android NDK.